# OpenGL Spotlights

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I'm trying to make 'spotlights' over a pool table in openGL. This should be fairly simple, but something is going wrong, and I can't work out what.

I have a class 'PoolLight' that I'm using as a sort of holding class for the lights. Here is is:

```
#include "PoolLight.h"
#include "Glut/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"

PoolLight::PoolLight() {

}

PoolLight::PoolLight(GLenum lightNumber, GLenum lightType, float red, float green, float blue, bool distant, float posX, float posY, float posZ)
{
    this->lightNumber = lightNumber;
    this->lightType = lightType;

    color[0] = red; color[1] = green; color[2] = blue; color[3] = 1;
    position[0] = posX; position[1] = posY; position[2] = posZ; position[3] = (int) (!distant);
    glLightfv(lightNumber, lightType, color);
    glLightfv(lightNumber, GL_POSITION, position);

    enabled(true);
}


PoolLight::~PoolLight(void)
{
}

void PoolLight::setSpotlight(float angle, float attenuation, float dirX, float dirY, float dirZ) {
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, angle);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, attenuation);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    spotDirection[0] = dirX; spotDirection[1] = dirY; spotDirection[2] = dirZ;
    glLightfv(lightNumber, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spotDirection);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 60);
}

void PoolLight::enabled(bool enabled) {
    if (enabled) glEnable(lightNumber);
    else glDisable(lightNumber);
}

void PoolLight::reposition() {
    glLightfv(lightNumber, GL_POSITION, position);
}
```

And in Display::Init, I have this code:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glPointSize(6);

//Lighting
middleSpotlight = PoolLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, .3, .3, 0.15, false, 0, 0, 50);
middleSpotlight.setSpotlight(60, 1, 0, 0, -1);
upperSpotlight = PoolLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, .3, .3, 0.15, false, 0, 45, 50);
upperSpotlight.setSpotlight(60, 1, 0, 0, -1);
lowerSpotlight = PoolLight(GL_LIGHT2, GL_DIFFUSE, .3, .3, 0.15, false, 0, -45, 50);
lowerSpotlight.setSpotlight(60, 1, 0, 0, -1);
```

However, even when disabling all but the middle spotlight my scene is uniformly lit with a sort of 'blanket' lighting.

I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious, but I just can't see what.

Comment: Aren't angles specified in radians? With `60` as your angle it seems like you are using degrees.

Comment: I changed it to (60.0 * (3.1415/180)) but to no avail.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of anything else right now - sorry.

Comment: Does disabling all spotlights remove the lighting? If you change things to point lights, does the lighting behave as espected? Are you sending the correct normals to the graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how OpenGL default fixed function pipeline implements lighting: Lighting is evaluated only at the vertices, the resulting colour interpolated over the surface. If your whole table consists of just one large quad, exactly this happens.

Solution 1: Subdivide the mesh to a high degree.

Solution 2: Replace fixed function lighting with a per-fragment-illumination shader.

Comment: The mesh was already in 20 triangles, but I just made it 200 and there's no difference. I have to use the fixed function lighting (it's a piece of coursework), and I don't really have time now to learn other methods. :< Would you like a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, please supply some screenshot, and also some code showing how you draw the mesh itself.